# How to make user go to application page instead directly go to application

Tags: flash, facebook

Currently i'm developing a facebooks apps with falsh application. i've have completed the development with all API  required to run a facebook apps. Everything went well and it's live now.

My question :
1. How can make user to go directly to the application page everytime they click the link posted by user who already use the application instead going to the canvas page applications.

i would appreciate if i can get hold of this answer as i'm been trying to look for the article that support saying that user will go directly to application directly to canvas application page instead of going to the application page.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible.

If users click a bookmark to your app they'll go directly to the app's canvas URL. Also, if  your app sends requests, or uses the achievements API, those will link back to your app's canvas. You can use links back to your canvas in stream posts, etc.

If users click the app name in search, the name of the app in the post attribution '(posted X minutes ago via Appname', they'll go to the information page for the app.

A workaround is to install a page tab on your app info page with a splash screen / 'please go to our app by clicking here' message - and make that the default landing tab of the page.

(example: https://www.facebook.com/EmpiresAndAllies?sk=app_4949752878 - this is the page you're brought to if you search for `Empires and Allies` and click the search result )